# is there an easy free way to create test case management in Jira

Tags: jira

I think the only part I dont get is how you handle the run results.  So if I set up a new project in Jira for test cases how would I make it so I can run mark a test case as pass or fail but not close out the jira.

So I basically want the original jira to be always open then be able to mark it passed or failed against a specific release.  the original jira should stay unchanged just somehow log a result set?

I do  not have bamboo

that make any sense

Answer (score 6):

We have setup a simple custom workflow in Jira without using Confluence.
We added one new issue type - Test Case. And we have a new sub-task - Test Run.

**Test Case** has only three workflow actions: **Pass**, **Fail** and **Invalid** (the last one is to make Test Case redundant). And two statuses - Open and Invalid.

**Test Run** is automatically created when Test Case passes or fails. Users do not manually create test runs. We use one of the plugins to create a subtask on transition.
**Test Run** can be in a **Passed** or **Failed** state and has version info, user who passed or failed and a comment.

This is it.

Here are some links that I used to setup Jira for Test Case Management:

- [Test Case Management in Jira](http://www.testandtry.com/2009/07/31/test-case-management-in-jira-2/)
- [Using Jira for Test Case Manangement](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFEVAL/Using+JIRA+for+Test+Case+Management)
- [Create On Transition Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/697735)

Comment: if question was about free solution, then it would be worth to mark that the transition plugin is payed solution.

Answer (score 2):

The approach we are following is as follows

We use Confluence for implementing our test cases.
Each test case has its own page describing the setup, the scenario to run and all possible outcomes.

We have a test library page which is the parent of all these test cases.
When we want to start a validation cycle on a particular release, we use a script which
generates for each test case in confluence, a corresponding 'test run' issue.
(@DennisG - JIRA allows to define different issue types, each with its own workflow)

The summary is the summary of the testcase 
The description is the scenario and outcome of the testcase
We have a specific confluence link referring the testcase

The testrun issue workflow contains 4 stages

- Open
- In Progress
- Blocked
- Closed

And 3 resolutions

- Success
- Failure
- Review testcase

We then start validating all 'test run' isuses.
Using dashboard gadgets it is easy to see how many testcases still need to be run, how many are blocked, how many have been done, and how many have failed ...

In case the resolution is 'review testcase' we have the ability to adapt the testcase itself.
Conclusion - JIRA is certainly usable as a test execution management environment.  Confluence,
as a wiki provides an environment to build the necessary hierarchies (technical, functional).

Last point.
We start to extensively use Bonfire (a plugin for JIRA)
http://www.atlassian.com/en/software/bonfire
This shortens the 'manual' testing cycle considerably.
For us it had an ROI of a couple of weeks.

Hope this helps,

Francis

PS.  If you're interested to use the script send me a note.

Comment: Let me see if I've got this straight. You have a set of test cases defined in Confluence. For each validation cycle you generate a set of instances of a custom issue type called "test run".

Question: Doesn't the database get huge? If you have 100 test cases and 10 verification cycles, that's 1000 "test run" issues presumably with a big chunk of linked defects.

Comment: Well - define huge ...  

JIRA is still able to handle 1000's of issues.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [PractiTest](http://www.practitest.com/), a test management tool that integrates with JIRA. PractiTest covers your entire QA process, so you can use it to create Requirements, Tests and Test sets, and use the integration option to report issues in JIRA. you can also link between the different entities.

read more about PractiTest's [integration with JIRA](http://www.practitest.com/jira-test-management/)

Comment: ducati1212 asked about free way, and PractiTest is payed tool

Answer (score 1):

We are using this test case management called informup.
The [test case management is integrates with Jira](http://www.informup.com/test-case-management-with-jira.aspx).
In addition it has fully integration in the system so in case you want to use it as a test case management and a bug tracking system you can do it as well

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I'm not sure that using JIRA (or any other bug/issue tracking tool) as a test management tool is a good idea. The problem with this is that issue trackers usually have a single main entity (the issue), whereas test management tools usually distinguish between test cases and actual tests/results. This way you can easily reuse the same test case for different releases and also store a history of test results. Additional entities such as test runs and test suites also usually make it a lot easier to manage and track your data. So instead of using Jira for test management, you might want to consider using a dedicated test management software that integrates with Jira. There are many test management tools out there, including open source projects:

http://www.opensourcetestmanagement.com/

You could also take a look at our tool TestRail, which also comes with Jira integration:

http://www.gurock.com/testrail/

http://www.gurock.com/testrail/jira-test-management.i.html

Comment: There are lots of benefits to staying in a single interface like Jira so if I can make Jira do what I need that would be the best solution.  I do agree with what you say though and thats my biggest issue right now is how to do a test set or test run from the base test case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in Jira's plugin directory at https://plugins.atlassian.com to see whats available to extend the core functionality. There may be something there that you could be installed.

There are tools out there that combine both issue tracking and test management (e.g. elementool.com), however if you are after a more feature rich issue tracking experience, you may need to start looking at dedicated tools.

If after looking around you find that there are no suitable solutions to enable you to have things in one place, you may want to take a look at [TestLodge test case management](http://www.testlodge.com), which is a tool I have developed that integrates easily with Jira.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just integrate JIRA with a test management tool? So, for example, we use Kualitee. It integrates with JIRA and provides traceability from the defect reported to the underlying test case and requirements. So, you can run your entire QA cycle on Kualitee and sync and assign defects to your team in JIRA.

You can also generate your test case execution reports and bug reports and export them so you are all set on that front as well.